# Get list items rest call with caml query

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, sharepoint-2013

[image: Function getlistitems]

[image: getlistitembyview]

[image]

I have 3 pictures. I tried to get list items by caml query but it show error box. function getListItems work well to return caml query but function GetListItemsByView does not work. This is sharepoint get list item should work in different site collection. Someone help please!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Modify the GetListitemsByView function as below.

```
function GetListitemsByView(webAppUrl,LibraryName,Text_CAML_Query){
    var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + Text_CAML_Query + '</Query></View>';
    var queryPayload = {  
        'query' : {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
            'ViewXml' : viewXml  
        }
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: webAppUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + LibraryName + "')/getitems",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
                $("#a").append("<li><div>"+item.Title+"</div></li>");
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {         
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```